# what is the "orange collection icon"?

Tags: materials, outliner

i downloaded the demo blender file the lone-monkey, which is some kind of hindu temple.
when trying to apply a material to the collum icon it is just greyed out, i mean it is not possible to add a new material.
also it doesnt have an option to enter in edit mode.
name of the file is lone-monk_cycles_and_exposure-node_demo.blend
Also, what is the meaning of this icon that looks like a double collection icon and it is orange in color?

[image: this is the outline window]

Comment: It looks like a collection instance, which means that you can't edit the collection instance, only the original objects that are in the original collection, you need to look for a collection called "column"

Comment: Yes, as @moonboots said, it's an instance collection (a duplicated object link it to the original one) everything that you change inside the original collection is going to affect the instance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a *Collection Instance*. You can't directly edit a collection instance, you need to find the original collection in order to edit the object it contains. By default a collection instance has the same prefixe as the original, in your case you need to find the collection called *column*.